# Bluetooth discovery of all services with a specific UUID

Tags: java, android, sockets, bluetooth

Can an Android application get the list of available sockets on a remote device which are SDP registered to a specific UUID? I can see how to connect to a single socket with the given UUID, but I cannot find a way to iterate through all the sockets which share that UUID.

I know my code is crap. I know I'm not supposed to do blocking operations in the Activity, and that everything here is completely hacky. I'm only trying to get a proof of concept running before I architect this correctly.

That said, here's my code. I took an approach which isn't working.

```
package {intentionally removed};

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.*;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    private String MY_TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            // Device does not support Bluetooth
        }
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            //Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            //startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            Toast error = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enable BT and try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            error.show();
            Log.e(MY_TAG, "BT not enabled. Quitting.");
        }

        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        Log.i(MY_TAG, "Found " + pairedDevices.size() + " bonded devices");
        // If there are paired devices
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {

            // Loop through paired devices
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                int i = 1;
                while (true) {
                    Log.i(MY_TAG, "Device " + device.getAddress() + " with name " + device.getName());
                    //Repeatedly try to connect to the SDP UUID; move to the next device when this fails.
                    BluetoothSocket s = null;
                    try {
                        s = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString("{intentionally removed}"));
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        try{
                            s.connect();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.i(MY_TAG, "could not connect to socket.");
                            break;
                        }
                        Log.i(MY_TAG, "Connected to a socket! Whee! " + i + " found.");
                        InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
                        Log.i(MY_TAG, "got the stream");
                        while (true) {
                            Log.i(MY_TAG, "began read loop");
                            int j = -1;
                            try {
                                j = is.read();
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                //RESUME NEXT...mwahahaha
                            }
                            if (j == -1) {
                                Log.i(MY_TAG, "ran out of ibytes");
                                break;
                            }
                            Log.i(MY_TAG, "ibyte: " + is.read());
                        }
                        i++;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        Log.e(MY_TAG, "Unable to connect.", e);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }

}
```

(the UUID I pulled because I'd rather not reveal what I'm up to. It's someone else's.)

I know there to be multiple sockets serving the same UUID on the other end. The code I've just given tries to connect to each socket, forcing `createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord` to grab another socket. However, one of the sockets I am unable to connect to...leaving me no way to iterate to the next one (as `createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord` just returns the same socket next iteration).

Is there a saner way to do this? I want a nice function I can call which lists out all of the sockets I can connect to with a given UUID. Does such a thing exist?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it exists. How it works:

1. You create a class i.e. GattAttributes that includes known UUIDs.
2. Discover Services and Characteristics in your Service class
3. Loop through the discovered Services and Characteristics in your Activity (optionally, you can populate a list for the user to see)

This gives you the available Services and Characteristics in a list.

> Look at this [Google Bluetooth LE example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothLeGatt) to see the code.

The example lets user choose the Characteristic, but if you want to connect to the concrete Characteristic, that you know beforehand (as I did):

- In your Service class, within onServicesDiscovered put:

  ```
  BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = gatt.getService(SERVICE_UUID).getCharacteristic(CHARACTERISTIC_UUID);
  ```
- If you want to also add notifications and utilize onCharacteristicChanged(), use this code:

> ```
> // Enable notifications for this characteristic locally
> gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);
>
> // Write on the config descriptor to be notified when the value changes
>  BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG);
>  descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
>  gatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
> ```

`CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG` needs to be defined, see the Google code referenced above.